# Need to backup existing deployed firebase function

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I need to backup existing function (nodejs) on production firebase project. I have check docs and unfortunately can't find information how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download or backup your deployed Firebase Function by following the steps:

1. Go to [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com), and select the project where your function deployed.
2. Click the Functions to go to the dashboard
3. Hover over the function name to show the vertical 3 dots and click the 3 dots.
4. Click Detailed usage stats and it will redirect to Google Cloud Cloud Function Console.
5. Look for **SOURCE** panel(between DETAILS and VARIABLE) and click.
6. Find the **DOWNLOAD ZIP** button in the right side of screen and click.

It will start to download your latest source of your function in a zip file.